# The best way to add NULL values to the database when my textboxes are empty

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server

**The problem was on executeScalar where my sql statement didn't return anything**

I have some values in my tables that are type of Int32, others of datetime which are nullable.
And what I want is when the user doesn't fill the textbox to insert a null value instead of ""(whitespace) which is incorrect type for my field.

[image]

I have tried ideas like:

```
insertActor.Parameters.AddWithValue("@School2StartYear", String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSchool2StartYear.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)Int16.Parse(txtSchool2StartYear.Text));
```

I have to do this for my **15 tables(with 30+ fields).**

I also seen the `.validate()` function by jQuery but I didn't tried it at all.

I have also seen this idea: `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]`

Do I have to do it in Database? When a '' is added convert it to NULL?

**So is this the best way to do it? Checking all the textboxes if they are IsNullOrWhiteSpace**

Comment: How is it not working?  Do you get an exception? Unexpected update values?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Does it work when you enter values?  Everything looks ok from the DB side... I would think it's failing before it gets that far along given that it's a NullReferenceException and not some type of DB exception.

Comment: And is it failing on that line of code, or later in the process when the statement is executed?

Comment: It has the same error when I enter all the values.
It is failing when the statement is executed: newID = Int32.Parse(insertActor.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

Comment: Can you show your sql statement

Comment: OMG I forgot to insert the "SELECT @@IDENTITY"; at the end of my sql statement! Sorry guys! 
Is it better to delete this post?

Comment: You should try posting your entire query along with the stack trace which will help us solve the problem . My guess which turned out to be correct was, you might not be returning any value from ur sql so error in ExecuteScaler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is probably caused because the result of the statement is null, not because your input values are incorrect.  Try splitting apart the execution like this:

```
object result = insertActor.ExecuteScalar();
newID = Int32.Parse(result.ToString());
```

I would suspect that result is null, which is causing a NullReferenceException when the ToString method is called.

Is the new id supposed to be coming from a return statement, an output parameter, a select statement?

Comment: I forgot to insert the "SELECT @@IDENTITY"; to my sql statement, so it didn't return anything!

Is it better to delete this post? It will confuse others!

Answer (score 1):

I usually just exclude the parameter:

```
Int16 school2StartYear;
if (Int16.TryParse(txtSchool2StartYear.Text, out school2StartYear) {
    insertActor.Parameters.AddWithValue("@School2StartYear", school2StartYear);
}
```

Your SQL code would declare the parameter as `@School2StartYear smallint = NULL` so that if the parameter is excluded, it uses `NULL` as the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with IsDBNull

```
Convert.IsDBNull (txtSchool2StartYear) ? 0:int.Parse (txtSchool2StartYear);
```